# Methods to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\sigma x^n}\cos(ax^n)\, dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

I was trying some things out to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\sigma x^n}\cos(ax^n)\, dx}$ but I couldn't figure out some of the details. For example :

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\sigma x^n}\cos(ax^n)\, dx}\\
&=\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x^n(\sigma-ai)}\, dx}\\
&=\Re\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-t(\sigma-ia)}t^{1/n-1}\, dt}\\
&=\Re\frac{1}{(\sigma - ia)^{n+1}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}
+1\right)\end{align}$$

with the last bit using $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-st}t^n\,dt}=s^{-(n+1)}\Gamma(n+1)$ and $n\Gamma(n)=\Gamma(n+1)$. The formula doesn't seem right, but WFA says $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-5x^3}\cos(3x^3)\, dx \approx0.469$ but the formula says it's $-0.000480\dots$ (checked [here][1])

Another attempt :

$$
\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\sigma x^n}\cos(ax^n)\, dx}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\sigma x^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k}\frac{(ax^n)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\, dx}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\frac{a^{2k}}{(2k)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\sigma x^n}(x^n)^{2k}\,dx}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\frac{a^{2k}}{(2k)!}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\sigma t}t^{2k+1/n-1}\, dt}\\
&=\frac{1}{n\sigma}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\frac{a^{2k}}{(2k)!}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-u}\left(\frac{u}{\sigma}\right)^{2k+1/n-1}\, du}\\
&=\frac{1}{n\sigma^{1/n}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\frac{\left(\frac{a}{\sigma}\right)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\Gamma\left(2k+\frac{1}{n}\right)}
\end{align}
$$

Can the sum be simplified in this case and how can the first method be amended?

EDIT : Found the issue with the first attempt, instead I should've used $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-st}t^{1/n-1}\, dt}=s^{-1/n}\Gamma(1/n)$ which then yields the correct answer.
So $I=\Re\frac{1}{(\sigma - ia)^{1/n}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}
+1\right)$ Maybe it can be simplified further?
[1]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%20e%5E%28-5x%5E3%29cos%284x%5E3%29%200..inf

Comment: The integral becomes $I=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sigma }\right)}{n}\right)}{\left(a^2+\sigma ^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2 n}}}$ using *Mathematica* assuming $\sigma>0$, $a>0$, and $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Your last expression can be written as a hypergeometric function with just a little bit of massaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\cos t= \Re (e^{-ti})$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\sigma x^n} \cos \left(a x^n\right) d x \\
& =\Re \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\sigma x^n} e^{i a x^n} d x \\
& =\Re \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(\sigma-i a) x^n} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $y=  x^n$ converts the integral $I$ into a Gamma function.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\Re\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(\sigma-i a) y} \cdot \frac{1}{n} y^{\frac{1}{n}-1} d y \\
& =\frac{1}{n} \Re \int_0^{\infty} y^{\frac{1}{n}-1} e^{-(\sigma-i a) y} d y \\ &=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)}{n} \Re\left[\frac{1}{(\sigma-i a)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Expressing the last reciprocal into its polar form as
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{1}{(\sigma-i a)^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\sigma^2+a^2} e^{-i \tan ^{-1} \frac{a}{\sigma}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}  =\frac{e^{\frac{i}{n} \tan ^{-1} \frac{a}{\sigma}}}{\left(\sigma^2+a^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can conclude that $$
I=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)}{n} \Re\left[\frac{1}{(\sigma-i a)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right]=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)\cos \left(\frac{1}{n} \tan ^{-1} \frac{a}{\sigma}\right)}{n\left(\sigma^2+a^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2 n}}}
$$

Comment: You inadvertently dropped the Gamma function contribution.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Fixed.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure

Comment: and feel feee to up vote the comment

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The change of variables $x=u^{1/n}$,  $dx=\frac{1}{n}u^{\frac1n-1}\,du$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\int^\infty_0e^{-\sigma u}u^{\frac1n-1}\cos(au)du=\frac{\Gamma(\frac1n)}{n\sigma^{\frac1n}}\int^\infty_0 \cos(au)f(u;\frac1n,\sigma)\,du\tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}
where
$f(u;\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}e^{-\beta u}u^{\alpha-1}$ is the densitty function of the $\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). Here $\alpha=\frac1n$ and $\beta=\sigma$.

The integral in the right-hand-side of \eqref{zero} is the real part of the characteristic function (Fourier transform) of the $\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution:

$$\phi(a;\alpha,\beta)=\int^\infty_0 e^{iau}f(u;\alpha,\beta)\,du= {\displaystyle \left(1-{\frac {ia}{\beta }}\right)^{-\alpha }}$$

The latter can be obtained by computing first the Laplace transform of the gamma distribution
$$ L(a)=\int^\infty_0 e^{-au}f(u;\alpha,\beta)\,du= \left(1+{\frac {a}{\beta }}\right)^{-\alpha }$$
and then,  using analytic continuation to get
$$\phi(a)=L(-ia)$$

Th obtain the real part of $\Big(1-i\frac{a}{\beta}\Big)^{-\alpha}$ we take the principal branch of logarithm and notice that
$$
\Big(1-i\frac{a}{\beta}\Big)^{-\alpha}=\exp\Big(-\alpha\log\big(1-i\frac{a}{\beta}\big)\Big)$$
and
$$\log\big(1-i\frac{a}{\beta}\big)=\log\big|1-i\frac{a}{\beta}\big|+i\arg\big(1-i\frac{a}{\beta}\big)$$
which is easy to estimate.